# How to get the list of "standard" perl modules available in system?

Tags: perl, module

There is a phrase in `perlmodlib(1)`:

> It's possible that not all modules listed below are installed on your
>   system. For example, the GDBM_File module will not be installed if you
>   don't have the gdbm library.

How to get actual list of the standard modules installed in the system?

Comment: [Here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-list-all-installed-perl-modules-216603/#post1104292) is a script that will find all installed perl modules visible to the currently running perl version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cpan` command can do it:

```
% cpan -a
```

I wrote [App::Module::Lister](https://www.metacpan.org/module/App::Module::Lister) to do this job. Although it's a module, it's also a program that does what you want when you run it like a program:

```
% perl `perldoc -l App::Module::Lister`
```

Several other Stackoverflow questions answer this for particular modules, including:

- [How do I check whether a Perl module is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802107/how-do-i-check-whether-a-perl-module-is-installed?rq=1)
- [How can I check if I have a Perl module before using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it)
- [How to check availability of Perl, its version and presence of a required module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605545/how-to-check-availability-of-perl-its-version-and-presence-of-a-required-module?lq=1)

For your particular question, though, do you really care what's implementing your DBM features? Do you have some question about that?